# Running an old version of some software

Tags: boot, windows, iso, unetbootin

I don't want to mingle in any backstory, but all that needs to be known is that I have a computer with Ubuntu on it and I am trying to install Windows 8 from an ISO.

I am using the guide that can be found [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html) which is a little more than four years old. Now, I've been able to accomplish everything up to Step 2, at which point I am stuck. I have downloaded the file found on that page, which can be found [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html), and have attempted to use it, as directed, quote;

> "right click the downloaded Unetbootin file, select Properties and on the "Permissions" tab, check the "Allow executing file as program" box. Then simply double click it and it should open."

But, after having set checked the specified box and double clicking the file, nothing happens. Nothing is launched and nothing changes. I've been stuck here for several hours now, having failed to find a solution via Google.

Comment: I found an answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu), if anyone stumbles across this post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install Windows on the same drive you have already installed Ubuntu, keep in mind that you probably wont be able to dual-boot without making some changes to grub (or whatever boot manager you are using to boot Ubuntu). To avoid that I recommend installing first Windows and the Ubuntu (newer versiones detected the installed OSs and provide you with all the options you need to create the correct boot options). 
But, if you just want to create an usb windows installer, maybe this a duplicate question